# K8S Get deployment liveness probe status

Tags: go, kubernetes

We have defined K8s liveness and readiness probes in our **deployment** resource (we have defied there liveness...), we need with `client-go` lib to access this liveness probe, how can we do that?

I've tried it with the `client-go` lib

https://github.com/kubernetes/client-go

as follows:

```
client.Discovery().RESTClient().Get()
```

I've also tried to play around with the go library but did not find any **deployment** property on `client.CoreV1()`. However I do find `service` `pod` etc. What am I missing here?

`PodList, err := client.CoreV1().Pods("mynamespace").List(metav1.ListOptions{LabelSelector: "run=liveness-app"})`

At the end I need to get the pod liveness status according to the liveness probe which is defined in the deployment. I mean **live or dead**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How to do this depends on what you want to do.

### Deployment

The `Deployment` contains a PodTemplate, that is used for creating each replica.

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myapp
spec:
  replicas: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: myimage
        name: myapp
        livenessProbe:
          # your desired liveness check
```

You can get the desired PodTemplate from deployments using client-go

For example:

```golang
clientset := kubernetes.NewForConfigOrDie(config)
deploymentClient := clientset.AppsV1().Deployments("mynamespace")
deployment, err := deploymentClient.Get("myapp", metav1.GetOptions{})

for _, container := range deployment.Spec.Template.Spec.Containers {
    container.LivenessProbe // add your logic
}
```

**Note:** The `Deployment` only contains the desired PodTemplate, so to look at any status, you have to look at the created Pods.

### Pods

You can list the Pods created from the deployment by using the same labels as in the *selector* of the `Deployment`.

Example list of Pods:

```golang
pods, err := clientset.CoreV1().Pods(namespace).List(metav1.ListOptions{
    LabelSelector: "app=myapp",
})

// check the status for the pods - to see Probe status
for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    pod.Status.Conditions // use your custom logic here

    for _, container := range pod.Status.ContainerStatuses {
        container.RestartCount // use this number in your logic
    }
}
```

The `Status` part of a `Pod` contain `conditions:` with some `Probe`-information and `containerStatuses:` with `restartCount:`, also illustrated in the Go example above. Use your custom logic to use this information.

A Pod is restarted whenever the *livenessProbe* fails.

Example of a `Pod Status`

```yaml
status:
  conditions:
  - lastProbeTime: null
    lastTransitionTime: "2020-09-15T07:17:25Z"
    status: "True"
    type: Initialized
  containerStatuses:
  - containerID: docker://25b28170c8cec18ca3af0e9c792620a3edaf36aed02849d08c56b78610dec31b
    image: myimage
    imageID: docker-pullable://myimage@sha256:a432251b2674d24858f72b1392033e0d7a79786425555714d8e9a656505fa08c
    name: myapp
    restartCount: 0
```

Comment: Thanks, I try it out 1+, I see that it prints the liveness, however I need to get the status, which the prob is responsible, I mean to get live or not according to the pod liveness, How can I do it?

Comment: @bredstraruts there is no way to check status of the livenessprobe, because if it fails, the pod is killed and a new pod is created.

Comment: The closest you can get is `restartCount:` in the `containerStatuses:`

Comment: Thanks! what do you mean with your custom logic, could you provide example ? I need to know in the time that I call that its `up`, should I check anything in addition ?

Comment: It is a number, use that number how you would like to.

Comment: but how this number helps, if I see 5 `restartCount` in could be at any time,if the pod deployed a year ago and I got 5 restarts , does it say that the pod is live now (in the time I run the code to check...)? im not sure about this, could you please elboarte?

Comment: Could you please answer my previous question?

Comment: @bredstraruts if a livenessProbe ever fails, the Pod will be killed - and restarted.

Comment: Yes I know :) , my question is very simple, how with the api I know that the pod is up or down? `if container.State.Running != nil  -> problem`  is sufficient?or there is another way?

Comment: could you please answer my last question, I want to close it with the bounty ...thanks

Comment: @bredstraruts If a Pod's livenessProbe fails, it will be killed/restarted immediately, so you will never see a pod in your cluster that is "dead".

Comment: so this is not valid? `if container.State.Running != nil  -> problem` as I dont get the pod which dead?

Answer (score 2):

```
pods, err := client.CoreV1().Pods("").List(meta_v1.ListOptions{})
if err != nil {
    log.Fatal(err)
}

for _, pod := range pods.Items {
    for _, container := range pod.Spec.Containers {
        fmt.Println(container.LivenessProbe)
        fmt.Println(container.ReadinessProbe)
    }
}
```

You can iterate over pod.Items to get the container LivenessProbe and ReadinessProbe

Comment: Thanks, I need the `deployment` liveness probe, how can I get it ?

Comment: @bredstraruts The Deployment mostly contain a **template** for the Pods. The readinessProbes in a Deployment is part of the PodTemplates.

Comment: @Jonas - Could you please provide it as answer with example and I will check it and close the question with the bounty